# How to derive a template template class from boost::enable_shared_from_this?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, template-templates

How can one derive a template class with templated type from boost::enable_shared_from_this?

```
template<template<class T> class Container>
class Myclass : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<?> {
};
```

This didn't compile:

```
template<template<class T> class Container>
class Myclass : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Myclass<Container<T> > > {
};
```

Error: 'Myclass' is not a template type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your class is templated by template template parameter - you should use simply `Containter`.

```
template<template<class> class Container>
class Myclass : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Myclass<Container> >
{
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Normaly you use `boost::enable_shared_from_this` in the following way

```
class Myclass 
  : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Myclass>
{
  // ...
};
```

If you have a template this changes to

```
template<class T>
class Myclass 
  : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Myclass<T> >
{
  // ...
};
```

Where `Myclass<T>` is the type you would use for declaration in other context. You have to write the whole class name with template arguments. The short form `MyClass` is allowed only inside the the definition.

And for template template parameters you have to use

```
template<template<class> class T>
class Myclass 
  : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Myclass<T> >
{
  // ...
};
```

Which is exectly ForEveRs answer.